# General Approach for logging instance change in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to log the instance change in a Django project. I know, in the django admin, django has a history table for logging each individual change for instance, but I want a customized log model.

My previous model looks like following:

```
class MyLog(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeingKey(A, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    b = models.ForeingKey(B, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    c = models.ForeingKey(C, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    change = models.CharField(amx_length=256)
```

This works except for one case, deleting the instance. For example, if you delete an instance 'A', all the logs who was referring it will have field 'a' set to None, then log is useless.

I think I should do the following instead:

```
class MyLog(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
    c = models.IntegerField()
    change = models.CharField(amx_length=256)
```

The downside is that there is no explicit relationship between log and item it try to log, but I no longer losing any valuable information. And this seems the way Django logs instance change in history table.

My question will be, is this the correct approach? Or there are any more downside for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Django offers a number of [audit-trail packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/); do you need to track the change as a single text field (you have a typo for `max_length` and I'd make it a `TextField` anyway if you do want to go this route)? The nice thing about using those packages is it maintains better encapsulation and provides more flexibility.

Specific to your complaint about not working on delete, you could try using a [`pre_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-delete) signal. Are you using signals for this behavior in general? That would be the best approach.

Comment: TextField is the right choice and that is what I am using, so consider that as a typo in my post... I am using signal for logging, but it doesn't solve the deleting issue. If data is gone, it is gone anyway. I am considering using third-party package for logging, but that means I need to convert all my current log into new table for being consistent. I will think about that. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Think about decoupling audit logic entirely from your actual application. The application shouldn't know it's being audited, nor should it care. If there are no links, you don't have to worry about preserving relations. That said, it sounds like you may want to use a flag for "soft deletes" instead of truly deleting objects. Think about an abstract model with an active (or deleted) boolean, a custom manager that returns only the non-deleted items by default and that would also give you a hook to put all the audit logic into (if you keep it coupled of course :)

Answer (score 1):

From the relational perspective, logs should be deleted with the `A` to maintain ForeignKey integrity.

You should not have a model Log that you want to preserve with a foreign key to an object that you do not want to preserve.

The downside of your approach (with integers) is that you are not taking advantage of data integrity that the relational databases is providing to you.

What you probably want is to not delete A from the database, but rather have a flag on it with its state that changes to `"deleted"` when it is deleted by an user.

Another approach is to do not put the logs on the relational database. This is reasonable if you do not need to keep then relational (e.g. if you don't need to show then to the users).

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, but I don't fully agree with you. Per theoretical perspective, I think you are right about keeping the integrity of data and log. However, in the real world, there are many case admin user want to know the whole life cycle of an instance. So what I am thinking is that I still need to keep the log even the instance is gone, but be cautious about rendering it to user and using it anywhere else. Thank you for your advise anyway!

Comment: I think you can add that information to the question, so the answerer is aware of it. Same for your comment on Tom's answer.